# Azure function app not triggering from an Event Hub

Tags: python, azure, triggers, azure-functions, azure-eventhub

I have a event hub which is in Subscription A and a function app in Subscription B, i am trying to trigger the function app from the event hub in Subscription A, as per my research this should be possible and the correct connection string must be provided in the configuration of function app. I have done this but for some reason i am not able to trigger the function app.

Below is my function.json

```
{
  "scriptFile": "__init__.py",
  "bindings": [
    {
      "type": "eventHubTrigger",
      "name": "event",
      "direction": "in",
      "eventHubName": "%eventHubName%",
      "connection": "TestBench",
      "cardinality": "one",
      "consumerGroup": "$Default"
    },
    {
      "type": "eventHub",
      "name": "outputHub",
      "direction": "out",
      "connection": "outputConnection"
    }
```

I have double checked the "TestBench" (eventhubs) connection string and also eventhub's name, they are correct.

Below is my function app code in `__init__.py` :

```
def main(event: func.EventHubEvent, outputHub: func.Out[List[str]]):
    
    data=json.loads(event.get_body().decode('utf-8'))
    logging.info(data)
```

Answer (score 0):

Please verify if you have configured eventHubName property in the application setting of your function app as you have defined the binding as
"eventHubName": "%eventHubName%"

In case if this is correct then please validate whether the connection string is configured correctly or not.

I will suggest you to review the [Diagnostic and solve problem](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-diagnostics) blade on your function app that will help you diagnose the issue and the recommend solution to resolve your issue.

Please review the python example [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-event-hubs-trigger?tabs=in-process%2Cfunctionsv2%2Cextensionv5&pivots=programming-language-python#example) and test the same at your end.